# Рамка для содержимого сайта

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Как сделать рамку для контента? Делаю с помощью 3х дивов, но левый и правый отображаются, а средний нет.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font: 12px/18px Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
a {
  color: blue;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
p {
  margin: 0 0 18px
}
img {
  border: none;
}
input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
}
/* Header
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#header {
  margin: 0 0 0 -148px;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 522px;
  background-image: url(images/head.jpg);
  background-position: center top;
}
/* Middle
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#content {
  margin: -120px auto 0;
  width: 950px;
  height: 1209px;
  background-color: #09192a;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.contlev {
  float: left;
}
.contbox {
  height: 1209px;
  width: 95%;
  background-image: url (images/contcent2.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  float: left;
}
.contprav {
  float: left;
}
/* Footer
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#footer {
  width: 1280px;
  margin-top: -215px;
  height: 310px;
  background-image: url(images/footer.png);
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
/* Logo
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#logo {
  padding: 26px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0px auto 0;
  width: 516px;
  height: 225px;
}
#logo img {
  width: 515px;
  height: 199px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="images/logo.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- #header-->

  <div id="content">
    <div class="contlev">
      <img src="images/contlev.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="contbox">
      Новости
    </div>
    <div class="contlev">
      <img src="images/contprav.png" />
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- #content-->

</div>
<!-- #wrapper -->

<div id="footer">

</div>
<!-- #footer -->
```

[image]

Comment: Код в студию, html + css

Comment: уточните пожалуйста не отображается именно рамка или вообще див?О_о

Comment: Думаю что рамка, а именно изображение которое назначено Bg для класса contbox, потому что при заливки этого дива к примеру белым цветом, он показывается там где и должен.

Answer (score 1):

насколько я понял, у вас трудности с 3х колоночной вёрсткой.

css:

```
.contleft{
  background:url(images/contlev.png) right bottom no-repeat;
  width:20px;
  float:left;
}
.contright{
  background:url(images/contprav.png) left bottom no-repeat;
  width:20px;
  float:right;
}
.contcenter{
  background:url(images/contcent.png) center bottom repeat-x;
  margin:0 20px;
}
.contcenter:after{
  clear:both;
  content:'';
  height:0px;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="contleft"></div>
<div class="contright"></div>
<div class="contcenter"></div>
```

Comment: там проблема именно с рамкой :)

Comment: сделал как написал deamondz, пропало вообще все кроме синего бек-фона контента.. как я понимаю наверное именно этот бек-фон закрывает собою мое изображение, как еще тогда объяснить то, что все исчезло. А в моем коде лев и прав изображения стоят не фоном для дива , а вставлены как рисунок, вот они и видны, но как тогда быть с ценр изображением!?

Comment: эмм, а вы хоть какие-то изменения под свой код делали? я же не знаю как там у вас всё.

Answer (score 0):

Тогда попробуйте заменить

```
background-image: url (images/contcent2.png);
```

на

```
background-image: url (/images/contcent2.png);
```

Comment: никаких изменений не произошло. Возможно есть какоето другое решение, как можно добавить рамку. Посмотрите на скрине

Comment: а у вас нет возможности в сеть выложить?<br>Или если выложено в сети дайте пож ссылку, тогда я точно вам помог бы

Comment: к сожалению только на локал

Comment: еще можете попробывать изменить png на jpg(несколько раз было у меня что png тупо не отображалось)

Comment: здесь ведь нужен img с прозрачностью, вот я добавил левую и правую стороны рамки, как видите с низу ее нет, как аналогично и сверху. Что можно сделать??

Comment: тогда попробуйте:<br>

>padding:20px 0; /*например, значение уже пробуйте сами...*/